# Open a locally installed android app through JS

Tags: javascript, android

I use QR & Barcode Scanner which automatically opens webpages (if the option is selected)

The QR codes are URLs which add items to a database.

The annoying thing is that once it is scanned you have to manually close the browser or swap which app is showing.

My thinking is that if I was able to automatically open this application after the page has loaded, scanning would be a much smoother process.

The alternative is that I build my own browser for android which i set to close after a certain time, but it does seem a bit overkill if I could just do a simple redirect.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would a webview inside the app be any helpful? Are you the owner of the web pages or are external links?

Comment: @FabioF. I am the website owner, but not the app owner

Comment: can you use a url scheme to redirect? like myapp://something That would require minor changes in the app, not sure if you're able to request them.

Comment: @FabioF. that was what I was hoping, Not likely to get the information from the application owner